# HashMap doesn't add values after @InjectMocks. The hashmap is inside class with the annotation

Tags: java, dependency-injection, mockito, java-ee-6, java-ee-5

The problem is that nothing is added to my cache. My class is much bigger so I provide here to minimum example that should reproduce the problem.
Let's say I have a dictionary class, which uses some initialService to return hashMap with initial values.

```
public class Dictionary() {
    @Inject
    private InitialService initialService;
    
    private Map<String, String> map;
    
    public Map<String, String> constructMap() {     
        HashMap<String, String> initialMap = initialService.getHashMap("initialKey", "initialValue");
        return initialMap;
    }
    
    public void saveConstructedMap() {
        map = constructMap();
    }
    
    public Map<String, String> getMap() {
        return map;
    }
}
```

Then I have a test with mockito. So firstly I save the map with method `saveConstructedMap()` then I get the map with `getMap()` and then I add there value.
I would expect the value to be there but the map is empty.
Even if I don't save it to new value but will do the put on `getMap()` so `getMap().put(...)`

```
public class DictionaryTest() {
    @Mock
    private InitialService initialService;
    
    @InjectMocks
    private Dictionary dictionary;
    
    public void test() {
        dictionary.saveConstructedMap();
        HashMap<String, String> myMap = dictionary.getMap();
        myMap.put("key","value");
        assertTrue(myMap.containsKey("key")); //returns false (the entry is not added)
    }
}
```

From what I understand the Mock just mocks the class so its empty inside, but `@InjectMocks` injects the specified mock and creates an object but in normal way (like I would do it with constructor for the Dictionary. So all the methods and fields should behave as in normal class, not test one. Did i misunderstand something here?)
Does anyone know what should i do to achieve what i want?

Of course i have `initMocks(this)` in the `setUp()` method which is annotated with `@Before`,

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `DictionaryTest` can't be compiled, e.g. because of `HashMap<String, String> myMap = dictionary.getMap();` line (should be `Map<String, String>`). Probably you've written it just for the question.

Nevertheless, the main idea of mock testing is to provide a custom implementation of mocked class' methods. In this case, you should do it for the `getHashMap` method of `InitialService` mock. The example is below:

```
Map<String, String> initialMap = new HashMap<>();
initialMap.put(initialKey, initialValue);
Mockito.when(initialService.getHashMap("initialKey", "initialValue")).thenReturn(initialMap);
```

If you don't do that, Mockito will set the default value as a result of the method ([in this case, it would be null](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.11.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing)):

> By default, for all methods that return a value, a mock will return either null, a primitive/primitive wrapper value, or an empty collection, as appropriate.

Another approach is to make [a partial mock](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#partial_mocks) and use real implementations of  its methods where needed. But don't take advantage of it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but of course I forgot to add this piece of code here (I have it in my project). I have when... then... for initial service, but it still doesn't work

Comment: I was wondering if it is because of the field? maybe fields cannot be accessed in the class which is @InjectMocks annotated.

Comment: wait, it actually started working, but...i dont get it... I have to think it through